Question about meaning of "bar"-ing in the context of Dirac fields
Following chapter 38 of Srednicki, "bar"-ing means (based on eq. 38.15)
$$\bar{A} = \beta A^\dagger\beta$$
One can show for instance that $$\bar{\gamma^\mu} = \gamma^\mu$$ My question is, using the definition (eq. 36.39): $$\gamma^\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^\mu \\
\bar{\sigma^\mu} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ we try to find the bar so we get
$$\beta(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger\beta = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I\\
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^\mu \\
\bar{\sigma^\mu} & 0
\end{pmatrix}^\dagger\begin{pmatrix}
0 &I\\
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
would the $\dagger$ in the $A^\dagger$ mean to transpose the matrix as a 4x4 or as a 2x2?I.e, is $$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}^\dagger =\begin{pmatrix}
A^* & C^* \\
B^* & D^*
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are 2 by 2 matrices. Or $$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}^\dagger =\begin{pmatrix}
A^\dagger & C^\dagger\\
B^\dagger & D^\dagger
\end{pmatrix}$$ Which of these 2 is what is meant by the author? For a general matrix, they are different because the component matrices may be not hermitian.


I.e, is $$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}^\dagger =\begin{pmatrix}
A^* & C^* \\
B^* & D^*
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are 2 by 2 matrices. Or $$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}^\dagger =\begin{pmatrix}
A^\dagger & C^\dagger\\
B^\dagger & D^\dagger
\end{pmatrix}$$ Which of these 2 is what is meant by the author? For a general matrix, they are different because the component matrices may be not hermitian.

Assuming the usual meaning of the $\dagger$ symbol (complex-conjugate transpose), the second equation is correct and the first equation is not correct.
The first equation is only correct if $B$ and $C$ are numbers, but it not correct in your case where $B$ and $C$ are 2x2 matrices.

Okay, I checked with my Prof and this is indeed the right answer. He also said that the 2x2 matrices are just more confusing than just thinking about it all as 4 by 4's
